# CSS property if webpage height exceeds viewport height

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way I can apply CSS property only if the page exceeds the viewport height?
@media won't work I think since it only checks the viewport dimensions but doesn't compare it with the actual webpage.

Comment: Not without JavaScript afaik

Comment: purely out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript you can do it like this:

```
let height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                   html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
if (height > window.innerHeight) {
    // you can put your styles here
};
```

Comment: And I guess I could've also add that to let's say add class you can do `document.querySelector('h1').className += ' your-class'`. Notice space before `your-class` as it basically appends your-class to the end of className string.

Answer (score -1):

So are you saying that the @media doesn't work? or are you just adding it wrong, are you doing it like so: `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)`